# (net::ERR_CERT_UNABLE_TO_CHECK_REVOCATION)

Tags: crl

why do I get There are issues with the site's certificate chain (net::ERR_CERT_UNABLE_TO_CHECK_REVOCATION) in chrome when accessing an https page? [image]

according to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=5313

> This error means we cannot download the CRL or talk to the OCSP
>   responder

but I'm able to download the CRL manually

Comment: did you already see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865894/warnings-about-insecure-elements-on-some-https-sites-in-chrome-but-no-such-ele